# How to use $materialDialog

Tags: angularjs, material-design

`$materialDialog` is [Angular Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) component.

But how to use that component? Why it doesn't return anything like angular-ui bootstrap? How to retrive promise or result or whatever else, just closes modal?
Here's short example:

```
var test = $materialDialog({
        templateUrl: '/Assets/app/azured/partials/dialog.html',
        targetEvent: event,
        resolve:{
            item: function () {
                return item;
            }
        },
        appendTo: angular.element.find('dialog'),
        controller: ['$scope', '$hideDialog', 'item', function ($scope, $hideDialog, item) {
            $scope.name = item.Name;
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $hideDialog();
            }
            $scope.ok = function () {
                scope.name = '';
                $hideDialog();
            };
        }]
    });
    test.then(function (x) {
        console.log(x); //this prints destroyDialog function why?
    });
```

Where do we know what user pressed? Should i implement custom logic inside of $materialDialog? In that case i find it pretty strange.
Issue in github [237](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/237)

Comment: It would be nice if you provide the example as a plunker

Comment: [This?](https://material.angularjs.org/#/material.components.dialog/readme/overview) My code is same, look at demo, all it does is `destroyDialog` dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved like this

```
function DeleteItem(_list, _item) {
    azuredBlade.Load('listId');
    Api.Delete(_list, _item).then(function (x) {
        if (x) {
            azuredBlade.Deload('listId');
            Refresher();
        }
    });
}
function Dialog(event, item, tableName) {
    $materialDialog({
        templateUrl: '/Assets/app/azured/partials/dialog.html',
        targetEvent: event,
        resolve: {
            item: function () {
                return item;
            },
            tableName: function () {
                return tableName;
            },
            fn: function () {
                return DeleteItem;
            }
        },
        appendTo: angular.element.find('dialog'),
        controller: function ($scope, item, tableName, $hideDialog, fn) {
            $scope.name = item.Name;
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $hideDialog();
            }
            $scope.ok = function () {
                fn(tableName, item);
                $hideDialog();
            };
        }
    });
}
```

So the logic is outside of $materialDialog and passed within `fn resolve`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a blog post that shows a cleaner approach and includes a Plunker.

http://angularauthority.com/2015/04/28/creating-a-material-design-modal-service/